# Big-O of while loop with an indeterminate number of iterations

Tags: random, time-complexity, big-o

I can't seem to rationalize the Big-O notation for a while loop that has an indeterminate number of iterations.

In my code for a personal project, I have a list containing all 0s. I then implement a while loop that will generate a random integer between 0 and 9. If the value in the list at the index of the random number is a 0, then the value is written to a 1 and the while loop exits. Otherwise, a random number is generated again and the process repeats.

I'm not entirely sure what the time complexity of this would be, however. For example, if after 9 iterations of the algorithm, every single value in the list except index 9 is 1, and if the random number generator just happens to not generate the number 9 for, say, 99 iterations, then it would exit after 99 + 9 iterations. Wouldn't the worst-case be O(infinity)? I don't think this is possible, but I figured I'd ask since I wasn't sure.

My textbooks and online resources don't seem to provide much insight on examples such as this. I'm sure that the best-case would be O(1), but the average and worst cases I'm a bit unsure about.

---

I found a similar problem that has the same premise. Here's the pseudocode, where n is some integer of arbitrary size:

```
sample_found = false
while(!sample_found) {
    if (rand(0,n) == 0) {
        sample_found = true
    }
}
```

In the worst case, this would run infinitely, right? I'm not sure about average case, either.

Comment: Big-O isn't the best tool to analyze a non-deterministic algorithm. It doesn't take into account the diminishing likelihood of worst case outcomes. I would look at it from a probabilistic/statistical point of view and look at [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) number of iterations, [variance/std dev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), etc.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea. I'd imagine that would involve some combinatorics knowledge that I'd have to touch up on. Any idea on what the statistical analysis approach would involve?

Comment: I'd have to touch up on it, too. Thus, no answer from me, just a comment. :)

Comment: *...I have a list containing all 0s...I then ... generate a random integer between 0 and 9 ... If the value in the list at the index of the random number is a 0, then the value is written to a 1 and the while loop exits...* Since the list starts out all 0s that means the first time through, no matter what index you generate, the value at that index is zero and loop exits.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) to control looping, with a probability `p=0.1` of continuing. Assuming that's the case, you can just use the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

The mean of this distribution is just `1/p`, so 10, and I'd use [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) to further understand how many draws would be needed to finish.  For example:

- 10% of the time you'd expect to finish immediately
- 50% of the runs you'd need to loop 6 times or less
- 90% of runs finish by 21 loops
- 99% of runs finish by 43 loops

calculated in R, using `qgeom(c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.99), 0.1)`.

The worst case obviously goes out to infinity, but in practice you'd be unlikely to loop 200 times.  `1-pgeom(200, 0.1)` gives 6e-10, so you can expect to iterate your loop more than a billion times before needing to wait this many iterations.